# Parallelizing the process

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I want to parallelize the spec which is generated by `_spectrum_generator`. I am using `futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` which is called in `_gather_lcms_data`. The spec is passed through  `function`. The file is in `.mzML` format.  Below is the output that i get which is empty.

```
(base) ashish@14-ce3xxx:~/GNPS_LCMSDashboard$ python3 lcms_map.py
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [mz, rt, i, scan, index, polarity]
Index: []
```

The output should be look like this:

```
(base) ashish@14-ce3xxx:/media/ashish/ubuntu7/GNPS_LCMSDashboard$ python3 lcms_map.py
           mz        rt            i  scan  index  polarity
0  169.038696  0.003722  1652.959961     1      1         1
1  177.969086  0.003722  1786.755127     1      1         1
2  194.156967  0.003722  1802.361450     1      1         1
3  154.059418  0.003722  1840.889160     1      1         1
4  164.080978  0.003722  1973.758423     1      1         1
5  150.079514  0.003722  1976.528687     1      1         1
6  160.096634  0.003722  2057.728516     1      1         1
7  201.182205  0.003722  2077.768311     1      1         1
8  162.078735  0.003722  2101.843018     1      1         1
9  171.044205  0.003722  2223.230713     1      1         1
```

Below is the code of _spectrum_generator:

```
def _spectrum_generator(filename, min_rt, max_rt):
   run = pymzml.run.Reader(filename, MS_precisions=MS_precisions)


   # Don't do this if the min_rt and max_rt are not reasonable values
   if min_rt <= 0 and max_rt > 1000:
       for spec in run:
           yield spec
   else:
       try:
           min_rt_index = _find_lcms_rt(run, min_rt) # These are inclusive on left
           max_rt_index = _find_lcms_rt(run, max_rt) + 1 # Exclusive on the right


           for spec_index in tqdm(range(min_rt_index, max_rt_index)):
               spec = run[spec_index]
               yield spec
           print("USED INDEX")
       except:
           run = pymzml.run.Reader(filename, MS_precisions=MS_precisions)
           for spec in run:
               yield spec
           print("USED BRUTEFORCE")
```

Below is code of lcms_map.py:

```
import os
import pymzml
import numpy as np
import datashader as ds
from tqdm import tqdm
import json
import pandas as pd
import xarray
import time
import utils

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go 

from utils import _spectrum_generator
from utils import _get_scan_polarity


from multiprocessing import Pool

import concurrent.futures

from multiprocessing import Process


# Enum for polarity
POLARITY_POS = 1
POLARITY_NEG = 2

def _gather_lcms_data(filename, min_rt, max_rt, min_mz, max_mz, polarity_filter="None", top_spectrum_peaks=100, include_polarity=False):
    all_mz = []
    all_rt = []
    all_polarity = []
    all_i = []
    all_scan = []
    all_index = []
    spectrum_index = 0
    number_spectra = 0

    all_msn_mz = []
    all_msn_rt = []
    all_msn_polarity = []
    all_msn_scan = []
    all_msn_level = []

    #fun(filename, min_rt, max_rt)

    for spec in _spectrum_generator(filename, min_rt, max_rt):
        rt = spec.scan_time_in_minutes()
        try:
            # Still waiting for the window
            if rt < min_rt:
                continue
                # pass
            
            # We've passed the window
            if rt > max_rt:            
                break

        except:
            pass

        if polarity_filter == "None":
            pass
        else:
            scan_polarity = _get_scan_polarity(spec)
            if polarity_filter != scan_polarity:
                continue
        
        if spec.ms_level == 1:
            spectrum_index += 1
            number_spectra += 1

            try:
                # Filtering peaks by mz
                if min_mz <= 0 and max_mz >= 2000:
                    peaks = spec.peaks("raw")
                else:
                    peaks = spec.reduce(mz_range=(min_mz, max_mz))

                # Filtering out zero rows
                peaks = peaks[~np.any(peaks < 1.0, axis=1)]

                # Sorting by intensity
                peaks = peaks[peaks[:,1].argsort()]
                peaks = peaks[-1 * top_spectrum_peaks:]

                mz, intensity = zip(*peaks)

                all_mz += list(mz)
                all_i += list(intensity)
                all_rt += len(mz) * [rt]
                all_scan += len(mz) * [spec.ID]
                all_index += len(mz) * [number_spectra]

                # Adding polarity
                if include_polarity is True:
                    scan_polarity = _get_scan_polarity(spec)
                    if scan_polarity == "Positive":
                        all_polarity += len(mz) * [POLARITY_POS]
                    else:
                        all_polarity += len(mz) * [POLARITY_NEG]
            except:
                pass
        elif spec.ms_level > 1:
            try:
                msn_mz = spec.selected_precursors[0]["mz"]
                if msn_mz < min_mz or msn_mz > max_mz:
                    continue
                all_msn_mz.append(msn_mz)
                all_msn_rt.append(rt)
                all_msn_scan.append(spec.ID)
                all_msn_level.append(spec.ms_level)

                # Adding polarity
                if include_polarity is True:
                    scan_polarity = _get_scan_polarity(spec)
                    if scan_polarity == "Positive":
                        all_msn_polarity.append(POLARITY_POS)
                    else:
                        all_msn_polarity.append(POLARITY_NEG)
            except:
                pass
            
    ms1_results = {}
    ms1_results["mz"] = all_mz
    ms1_results["rt"] = all_rt
    ms1_results["i"] = all_i
    ms1_results["scan"] = all_scan
    ms1_results["index"] = all_index

    msn_results = {}
    msn_results["precursor_mz"] = all_msn_mz
    msn_results["rt"] = all_msn_rt
    msn_results["scan"] = all_msn_scan
    msn_results["level"] = all_msn_level

    # Adding polarity
    if include_polarity is True:
        ms1_results["polarity"] = all_polarity
        msn_results["polarity"] = all_msn_polarity

    ms1_results = pd.DataFrame(ms1_results)
    msn_results = pd.DataFrame(msn_results)

    return ms1_results, number_spectra, msn_results

def _get_feather_filenames(filename):
    output_ms1_filename = filename + ".ms1.feather"
    output_msn_filename = filename + ".msn.feather"

    return output_ms1_filename, output_msn_filename

# These are caching layers for fast loading
def _save_lcms_data_feather(filename):
    output_ms1_filename, output_msn_filename = _get_feather_filenames(filename)
    start=time.time()

    # with Pool(5) as p:
    #     #ms1_results, number_spectra, msn_results = p.starmap(_gather_lcms_data, (filename, 0, 1000000, 0, 10000, "None", 100000, True))
    #     ms1_results, number_spectra, msn_results = _gather_lcms_data(filename, 0, 1000000, 0, 10000, polarity_filter="None", top_spectrum_peaks=100000, include_polarity=True)

    # with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    #     f=executor.submit(_gather_lcms_data, filename, 0, 1000000, 0, 10000, polarity_filter="None", top_spectrum_peaks=100000, include_polarity=True)
    #     ms1_results, number_spectra, msn_results = f.result()

    ms1_results, number_spectra, msn_results = _gather_lcms_data(filename, 0, 1000000, 0, 10000, polarity_filter="None", top_spectrum_peaks=100000, include_polarity=True)

    print(ms1_results.head(10))
    print("Gathered data in", time.time() - start)
    ms1_results = ms1_results.sort_values(by='i', ascending=False).reset_index()

    ms1_results.to_feather(output_ms1_filename)
    msn_results.to_feather(output_msn_filename)


_save_lcms_data_feather("/media/ashish/ubuntu7/GNPS_LCMSDashboard/QC_0.mzML")
```

How do i get the desired output by parallelizing. Suggest the changes that i need make in order to make it work.

Comment: I’d love to help you, and I’ve been doing some ThreadPoolExecutor stuff lately along with dataframes, but there is just *way* too much code here. Can you simplify the example? The more precise the question is, the easier it is to answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Simon Lundberg pointed out, you posted very complicated code, which makes it difficult to parallelize and even more difficult to explain how it is to be done. But if you were to present a simplified version of your code that was readily parallelizable, any answer would not be dealing with the complexities of your actual current code and would therefore be of little help. So I will try to create code that is an abstraction of your code's structure and then show how I would parallelize that. I am afraid that since you are not that familiar with multiprocessing, this may be rather difficult for you to follow.

First, a few observations about your code:

1. `_gather_lcms_data` currently is passed a filename and then using a generator function, `_spectrum_generator`, loops on all of its elements, called variable `spec`. In each loop iteration variable results are appended to various lists and variable `number_spectra` is optionally incremented. You have another variable `spectrum_index` that is also optionally incremented but its value is not otherwise used and could be eliminated. Finally, these lists are added to various dictionaries.
2. To parallelize the `_gather_lcms_data` function, it needs to process a single element, `spec` from the `_spectrum_generator` function so that we can run multiple invocations of this function in parallel. Consequently it needs to return a tuple of elements back to the main process which will do the necessary appending to lists and then create the dictionaries.
3. In your current code for each iteration of `spec` you optionally increment `number_spectra` and optionally append elements to various lists. Since we are now going to be parallelizing this function by returning individual elements, the main process must (1) accumulate the returned `number_spectra` value and optionally append the returned elements to result lists. Where in the original code you were not appending an element to a list for a given iteration, in the parallelized code you must return a `None` value so that the main process knows that for that iteration nothing needs to be appended.
4. In this abstraction, I have also reduced the number of lists down to two and I am generating dummy results.

First an abstraction of your current code.

```py
def _spectrum_generator(filename, min_rt, max_rt):
    #run = pymzml.run.Reader(filename, MS_precisions=MS_precisions)
    run = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    for spec in run:
        yield spec

def _gather_lcms_data(filename, min_rt, max_rt, min_mz, max_mz, polarity_filter="None", top_spectrum_peaks=100, include_polarity=False):
    # Remainder of the list declarations omitted for simplicity
    all_mz = []
    all_msn_mz= []
    number_spectra = 0

    for spec in _spectrum_generator(filename, min_rt, max_rt):
        ... # Code omitted for simplicity

        number_spectra += 1 # Conditionally done

        msn_mz = spec # Conditionally done
        all_msn_mz.append(msn_mz)

        mz = (spec * spec,) # Conditionally done
        all_mz += list(mz)
        ...
    ms1_results = {}
    msn_results = {}
    ...
    ms1_results["mz"] = all_mz
    msn_results["precursor_mz"] = all_msn_mz
    ...
    # Return
    return ms1_results, number_spectra, msn_results

def _save_lcms_data_feather(filename):
    ms1_results, number_spectra, msn_results = _gather_lcms_data(filename, 0, 1000000, 0, 10000, polarity_filter="None", top_spectrum_peaks=100000, include_polarity=True)
    print(ms1_results)
    print(number_spectra)
    print(msn_results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _save_lcms_data_feather("/media/ashish/ubuntu7/GNPS_LCMSDashboard/QC_0.mzML")
```

Prints:

```None
{'mz': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]}
6
{'precursor_mz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

This is the parallelized version of the above code:

```py
def _spectrum_generator(filename, min_rt, max_rt):
    #run = pymzml.run.Reader(filename, MS_precisions=MS_precisions)
    run = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    for spec in run:
        yield spec

def _gather_lcms_data(spec, min_rt, max_rt, min_mz, max_mz, polarity_filter="None", top_spectrum_peaks=100, include_polarity=False):
    # Remainder of the list declarations omitted for simplicity
    number_spectra = 0

    ... # Code omitted for simplicity

    number_spectra += 1

    msn_mz = spec # Conditionally done. If not done then set msn_mz to None

    mz = list((spec * spec,)) # Conditionally done. If not done then set mz to None
    ...
    return mz, number_spectra, msn_mz

def _save_lcms_data_feather(filename):
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    from functools import partial

    min_rt = 0
    max_rt = 1000000

    worker_function = partial(_gather_lcms_data, min_rt=min_rt, max_rt=max_rt, min_mz=0, max_mz=10000, polarity_filter="None", top_spectrum_peaks=1000000, include_polarity=True)
    with Pool() as pool:
        all_mz = []
        all_msn_mz = []
        number_spectra = 0

        for mz, _number_spectra, msn_mz in pool.map(worker_function, _spectrum_generator(filename, min_rt, max_rt)):
            if mz is not None:
                all_mz += mz
            number_spectra += _number_spectra
            if msn_mz is not None:
                all_msn_mz.append(msn_mz)
    ms1_results = {}
    msn_results = {}
    ms1_results["mz"] = all_mz
    msn_results["precursor_mz"] = all_msn_mz
    print(ms1_results)
    print(number_spectra)
    print(msn_results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _save_lcms_data_feather("/media/ashish/ubuntu7/GNPS_LCMSDashboard/QC_0.mzML")
```